Android Room - Query to only insert new entry if combination of two fileds do not exist
I have an Room table, with ID, Year and Week.

I need a query, that a new entry is only added if the combination of Year and Week does not exist in the table.
How can I archive this?
I created an initInsertWeek function. But I do not know how to archive this.
@Dao
interface WeeksDao {

    @Upsert
    suspend fun upsertWeek(week: Week)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun initInsertWeek(week: Week)
}


do you need an SQL-query or some code in Java?

I need a sql Query, that works with Android Room database. but I don't knwo how to do it

Do you have a unique index on the two columns year and week? That would - by design - prevent another entry being added with the same combination of values.

You could create a query method that checks if one exists and then create a transaction method to combine the check and the insert.
Something like this
@Query(SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE year = :year AND week = :week")
fun doesEntryExist(year: String, week: String): List<Week>

@Transaction
fun insertIfNotExist(week: Week){
    val entries = doesEntryExist(week.year, week.week)
    if(entries.isEmpty()){
        initInsertWeek(week)
    }
}


Thank you very much. This works perfectly

Perhaps consider re-visiting the @Entity annotated Week class. To a) utilise the suggested unique column (so that an insert can IGNORE the duplicate conflict), but to further optimise to consider also combining the two columns and to use a numeric rather than string value, this consuming less storage for the what is basically the same value.
e.g. perhaps have:-
@Entity(
    /* define the UNIQUE index, thus facilitating a catchable UNIQUE conflict if a duplicate is attempted */
    indices = [Index(value = ["yearAndWeek"], unique = true)]
)
data class Week(
    @PrimaryKey
    /* note autoGenerate not coded as not needed and inefficient
    *   BUT due to Room's handling of values default is NULL
    *   i.e Room, if autoGenerate is false, takes 0 to be ID 0 */
    val id: Long?=null,
    /* Combined year and week as a numeric (Int) and thus using less storage */
    val yearAndWeek: Int=0
) {
    /* additional constructors to handle combinations of Int and String values */
    constructor(year: Int, week: Int) : this(yearAndWeek = year * 100 + week)
    constructor(year: String, week: String) : this(yearAndWeek = (year.toInt() * 100) + week.toInt())
    constructor(year: Int, week: String) : this(yearAndWeek = (year * 100) + week.toInt())
    constructor(year: String, week: Int) : this(yearAndWeek = (year.toInt() * 100) + week)

    /* functions to get one of the two combined parts*/
    fun getYear(): Int = (yearAndWeek / 100)
    fun getWeek(): Int = (yearAndWeek % 100)
}


see comments

You could then have (in an @Dao annotated interface):-
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insert(week: Week): Long

This returning either the id or in the case of a duplicate -1 as the insert, due to the UNIQUE index and thus the UNIQUE conflict, the insert being ignored and the underlying SQLite convenience insert method returning -1.
Including:-
@Query("SELECT * FROM week")
fun getAllWeeks(): List<Week>

Allows the following code (run on the main thread for brevity):-
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    dao = db.getAllDAOs()

    var attempts=0
    var inserted=0
    for (y in  2000..2010) {
        for(w in 1..52) {
            attempts+=1
            if (dao.insert(Week(y,w)) > -1) inserted+=1
            /* various duplicates using other constructors that utilise a String for week or Year*/
            if (w % 10 == 0) {
                attempts+=1
                if (dao.insert(Week(y.toString(),w.toString())) > -1) inserted+=1
            }
            if (w % 4 == 0) {
                attempts+=1
                if (dao.insert(Week(y.toString(),w)) > -1) inserted+=1
            }
            if (w % 8 == 0) {
                attempts+=1
                if (dao.insert(Week(y,w.toString())) > -1) inserted+=1
            }
        }
    }
    Log.d("DBINFO","INSERT RESULTS. Attempt=${attempts} INSERTED OK=${inserted} IGNORED=${attempts-inserted}.")
    val allWeeks = dao.getAllWeeks()
    Log.d("DBINFO","There are ${allWeeks.size} rows. They are:-")
    for(w in allWeeks) {
        Log.d("DBINFO","\tID=${w.id} YearAndWeek is ${w.yearAndWeek} Year is ${w.getYear()} Week is ${w.getWeek()}")
    }

To Output:-
2024-12-30 11:32:17.028 D/DBINFO: INSERT RESULTS. Attempt=836 INSERTED OK=572 IGNORED=264.
2024-12-30 11:32:17.040 D/DBINFO: There are 572 rows. They are:-
2024-12-30 11:32:17.040 D/DBINFO:   ID=1 YearAndWeek is 200001 Year is 2000 Week is 1
2024-12-30 11:32:17.040 D/DBINFO:   ID=2 YearAndWeek is 200002 Year is 2000 Week is 2
2024-12-30 11:32:17.040 D/DBINFO:   ID=3 YearAndWeek is 200003 Year is 2000 Week is 3
2024-12-30 11:32:17.041 D/DBINFO:   ID=4 YearAndWeek is 200004 Year is 2000 Week is 4
2024-12-30 11:32:17.041 D/DBINFO:   ID=5 YearAndWeek is 200005 Year is 2000 Week is 5
2024-12-30 11:32:17.041 D/DBINFO:   ID=6 YearAndWeek is 200006 Year is 2000 Week is 6
2024-12-30 11:32:17.041 D/DBINFO:   ID=7 YearAndWeek is 200007 Year is 2000 Week is 7
2024-12-30 11:32:17.041 D/DBINFO:   ID=8 YearAndWeek is 200008 Year is 2000 Week is 8
2024-12-30 11:32:17.041 D/DBINFO:   ID=9 YearAndWeek is 200009 Year is 2000 Week is 9
2024-12-30 11:32:17.041 D/DBINFO:   ID=10 YearAndWeek is 200010 Year is 2000 Week is 10
....
2024-12-30 11:32:17.043 D/DBINFO:   ID=50 YearAndWeek is 200050 Year is 2000 Week is 50
2024-12-30 11:32:17.043 D/DBINFO:   ID=51 YearAndWeek is 200051 Year is 2000 Week is 51
2024-12-30 11:32:17.043 D/DBINFO:   ID=52 YearAndWeek is 200052 Year is 2000 Week is 52
2024-12-30 11:32:17.043 D/DBINFO:   ID=53 YearAndWeek is 200101 Year is 2001 Week is 1
2024-12-30 11:32:17.043 D/DBINFO:   ID=54 YearAndWeek is 200102 Year is 2001 Week is 2
2024-12-30 11:32:17.044 D/DBINFO:   ID=55 YearAndWeek is 200103 Year is 2001 Week is 3
2024-12-30 11:32:17.044 D/DBINFO:   ID=56 YearAndWeek is 200104 Year is 2001 Week is 4
....
2024-12-30 11:32:17.074 D/DBINFO:   ID=518 YearAndWeek is 200950 Year is 2009 Week is 50
2024-12-30 11:32:17.074 D/DBINFO:   ID=519 YearAndWeek is 200951 Year is 2009 Week is 51
2024-12-30 11:32:17.074 D/DBINFO:   ID=520 YearAndWeek is 200952 Year is 2009 Week is 52
2024-12-30 11:32:17.075 D/DBINFO:   ID=521 YearAndWeek is 201001 Year is 2010 Week is 1
2024-12-30 11:32:17.075 D/DBINFO:   ID=522 YearAndWeek is 201002 Year is 2010 Week is 2
2024-12-30 11:32:17.075 D/DBINFO:   ID=523 YearAndWeek is 201003 Year is 2010 Week is 3
....
2024-12-30 11:32:17.077 D/DBINFO:   ID=563 YearAndWeek is 201043 Year is 2010 Week is 43
2024-12-30 11:32:17.077 D/DBINFO:   ID=564 YearAndWeek is 201044 Year is 2010 Week is 44
2024-12-30 11:32:17.078 D/DBINFO:   ID=565 YearAndWeek is 201045 Year is 2010 Week is 45
2024-12-30 11:32:17.078 D/DBINFO:   ID=566 YearAndWeek is 201046 Year is 2010 Week is 46
2024-12-30 11:32:17.078 D/DBINFO:   ID=567 YearAndWeek is 201047 Year is 2010 Week is 47
2024-12-30 11:32:17.078 D/DBINFO:   ID=568 YearAndWeek is 201048 Year is 2010 Week is 48
2024-12-30 11:32:17.078 D/DBINFO:   ID=569 YearAndWeek is 201049 Year is 2010 Week is 49
2024-12-30 11:32:17.078 D/DBINFO:   ID=570 YearAndWeek is 201050 Year is 2010 Week is 50
2024-12-30 11:32:17.078 D/DBINFO:   ID=571 YearAndWeek is 201051 Year is 2010 Week is 51
2024-12-30 11:32:17.078 D/DBINFO:   ID=572 YearAndWeek is 201052 Year is 2010 Week is 52


i.e. the first line indicates that duplicates were ignored, whilst the second line confirms that only 572 rows exist. All subsequent lines show how   the combined data (Year and Week) and individual data can easily be extracted via the Week object.

However, if you wanted to SELECT data according to Year and or Week then  the underlying queries would be a little more complicated e.g. to select all weeks between a start and end week irrespective of year then you could have something like:-
@Query("SELECT * FROM week WHERE (yearAndWeek % 100) BETWEEN :lowerWeek AND :higherWeek")
fun getByWeeksBetween(lowerWeek: Int, higherWeek: Int): List<Week>


if according to year then yearAndWeek would instead be divided by 100

If you wish further information in regards to why autoGenerate=false, the default, has been suggested then you can refer to https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

(autoGenerate=true results in the AUTOINCREMENT constraint being added)

